# INDEX MATCH array formula for 1M rows

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have two sets of data that need to be matched based on IDs and timestamp (+/- 3 units converted from time), and below is the formula that I've been using in Excel to do the matching. Recently I've had to run this formula on up to 1 million rows in Excel, and it takes a REALLY long time, crashes too. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this, if not in Excel?

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,--(B:B=E3)*--(ABS(C:C-F3)<=3),0),1)
```

Data Set 1:
Column A: States
Column B: IDs
Column C: Timestamp

Data Set 2:
Column D: Email Addresses
Column E: IDs
Column F: Timestamp

**Column G**: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,--(B:B=E3)*--(ABS(C:C-F3)<=3),0),1)`

Goal: Append "States" Column to Data Set 2 matched on IDs and Timestamp (+/- 3 time units) match.

Just don't know how to run this formula on very large data sets.

Comment: Just from the TITLE of your question... this is a bad idea!

Comment: ...but to help... the double unary (--) is used twice in your formula and these are not necessary since you are already multiplying the two column results. Get rid of them. It should make a little faster.

Comment: I've got to go out on an errand. If this has not been answered by the time I return I'll have a go at a VBA routine to do it for you.

Comment: Can I see a small sample of the data in each column please?

Comment: I'm just about finished with a solution for you and I would like to test on a small representative sample, say a few hundred rows of data. Could you send that to me? My email address is:    daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: Please do send the file if you can (please see my previous comment), but also can you tell me how long this calculation takes to complete (if it does not crash first)?

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, it crashes with 1M rows, with 100k, it takes 15 mins. I will send over sample data now, thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following VBA routines in a standard code module.

Run the MIAB1290() routine.

This emulates the precise outcome of your INDEX/MATCH formula, but it is much more efficient. On my computer, a million records are correctly correlated and the results displayed in **Column G** in just 10 seconds.

```
Public Sub MIAB1290()

    Dim lastB&, k&, e, f, z, v, w, vErr, r As Range

    With [a2]
        Set r = .Resize(.Item(.Parent.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, 5).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1, .Item(, .Parent.Columns.Count - .Column + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column - .Column + 1)
        lastB = .Item(.Parent.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, 2).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
    End With

    With r
        .Worksheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort Key1:=.Item(1, 2), Order1:=1, Key2:=.Item(1, 2), Order2:=1, Header:=xlYes
        v = .Value2
    End With

    ReDim w(1 To UBound(v), 1 To 1)
    vErr = CVErr(xlErrNA)

    For k = 2 To UBound(v)
        e = v(k, 5)
        f = v(k, 6)
        w(k, 1) = vErr
        z = BSearch(v, 2, e, 1, lastB)
        If z Then
            Do While v(z, 2) = e
                If Abs(v(z, 3) - f) <= 3 Then
                    w(k, 1) = v(z, 1)
                    Exit Do
                End If
                z = z + 1
                If z > UBound(v) Then Exit Do
            Loop
        End If
    Next

    r(1, 8).Resize(r.Rows.Count) = w

End Sub


Private Function BSearch(vA, col&, vVal, ByVal first&, ByVal last&)
    Dim k&, middle&
    While last >= first
        middle = (last + first) / 2
        Select Case True
            Case vVal < vA(middle, col)
                last = middle - 1
            Case vVal > vA(middle, col)
                first = middle + 1
            Case Else
                k = middle - 1
                Do While vA(k, col) = vA(middle, col)
                    k = k - 1
                    If k > last Then Exit Do
                Loop
                BSearch = k + 1
                Exit Function
        End Select
    Wend
    BSearch = 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel isn't really made for large ammount of data, and probably no code will do it faster for you then a builtin excel formula. In this case, I would sugest you to give a try to the PowerPivot addin, and see how it handles the situation.

Comment: While PowerPivot may work well in this case, I suspect that a well-written VBA procedure would produce very acceptable results.

Comment: You can't handle this much info even in a Dictionary, and you can't possible think of looping thru all ranges. So, it's not about the structure, but the limitations of handling so much info and the delay to get any data from the applictation into the VBA.

Comment: Really? Umm... what are you talking about? A million rows by three columns? Easy and very fast in a variant array.

Comment: Indeed but no need for the external libraries (ADO/DAO). The native SAFEARRAY will do just fine.

Comment: You got me.. I don't know why I always tought the limitiation of an array was 256.. I think I confused it with Collection someday.. my bad xD

Comment: Israel, please see my answer.